# Bootstrap Tag AutoComplete with Ajax Support

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using this plugin in my site : http://sandglaz.github.io/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/

It's default options are :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('div#autotag').tagautocomplete({
        source: ['@ann', '@andrea', '@aaron', '@daryl', '@emma', '@faris', '@june', '@jane', '@jessica', '@john', '@myra', '@maria', '@mariam', '@mention', '@mona', '@omar', '@peter', '@quinn', '@rana', '@sam', '@simon', '@tom', '@upton', '@veronica', '@wayne', '@yasmin', '@zaid', '#work', '#product', '#marketing', '#customer'],
        character: '@#'  
      });
      $('div#autotag').first().focus();
    });
```

```html
<div id="example" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

But i want the source with "Ajax" Option, something like this :-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('div#poststatus').tagautocomplete({
    source: 'http://laravel.local/list',
    character: '@#'
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="example" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

And In list, Resources are :-

```html
['@ann', '@andrea', '@aaron', '@daryl', '@emma', '@faris', '@june', '@jane', '@jessica', '@john', '@myra', '@maria', '@mariam', '@mention', '@mona', '@omar', '@peter', '@quinn', '@rana', '@sam', '@simon', '@tom', '@upton', '@veronica', '@wayne', '@yasmin', '@zaid', '#work', '#product', '#marketing', '#customer']
```

But this is not working. Is it possible to make it ajaxified ?

i have textarea, where user will be typing more text & can have multiple tags too... something like twitter tweet box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you included this all files

```
          <script src="jquery.js"></script>
          <script src="deps/bootstrap-typeahead.js></script>
          <script src="deps/rangy-core.js></script>
          <script src="deps/caret-position.js></script>
          <script src="bootstrap-tagautocomplete.js"></script>
```

In that case you want to add some text and also tag someone then ideal plugin to use is

[**Mention Input js**](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/)

Try it

Comment: i  have initialised everything. and there is no error at all in console, but whenever i type `@a`, No lists are populated.

Comment: You can use typeahead of bootstrap which has many examples for dynamic data binding ..

Comment: i have textarea, where user will be typing more text & can have multiple tags too...  something like twitter tweet box

Comment: can't i extend current auto complete

Comment: try few cases and check what is restricting.. you will have to edit the core of plugin..

Comment: I think so, but i am just checking something with less work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a function to the source list and return the required items from it.

e.g.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('div#poststatus').tagautocomplete({
    source: function() { /* fetch and return data */ },
    character: '@#'
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

[please check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/173/)

[please check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/mtrff/94/)

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/bootstrap.min.js

```
<h5>Old way with just an array of strings:</h5>
<input type="text" class="test-attr-input" placeholder="Type 'A'" autocomplete=off>
<label class="test-attr-val"></label><br/>


$('.test-attr-input').typeahead({
    source: [
      'Alaska',
      'Alabama',
      'Illinois'
    ]

    // there would be no need to change this function; it is overridden just to show the value difference from the other typeahead
  , updater: function (item) {
      $('.test-attr-val').text('Value: '+item);
      return item
    }
});

$('.test-data-input').typeahead({
    source: [{
      display: 'Alaska',
      val: 'AK'
    },{
      display: 'Alabama',
      val: 'AL'
    },{
      display: 'Illinois',
      val: 'IL'
    }]

  , updater: function (item) {
      $('.test-data-val').text('Value: '+item.val);
      return item.display
    }

  , highlighter: function(item) {
      var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
      return item.display.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
      })
    }

  , matcher: function(item) {
      return ~item.display.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())
    }

  , sorter: function(items) {
      return items   
    }
});
```

Comment: u can check second link